# How to improve solution using OOP?

Tags: typescript, oop

I have one entity `Car` if two types `Big`, `Small`.

My HTML page contains two forms for each them. Depending of selected form, I aware about type: `Big`, `Small`.

My TypeScript looks as:

```
public type: "Big" | "Small";
public CarSmall: Car;
public CarBig: Car;
```

When form is submitted I call function:

```
public save(): void {
   if (this.type == "Big") {
        const bigCarProperties = {}; // Get data specialized for this type
        save(bigCarProperties) ;
   }

    if (this.type == "Small") {
        const smallCarProperties = {}; // Get data specialized for this type
        save(smallCarProperties);
   }
}
```

Where `save()` function accepts different number of parameters.

So, I don't like this approach, how to improve this using OOP in TypeScript?

Definitely, I can create two classes that extend parent class Car with method `Save();` But method `Save()` it is not property of Car, it is another zone of responsibility.

I don't need care about result outcoming object car, no matter which type, I need just save it.

Comment: I can apply factory pattern to create specific object of concrete class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not that you are calling save in save method ,I just move the logic related to get car properties to another function ,base in your code both small and big car is Car class instant so the save method should work for both object

```
getCarProperties(type:string) {
   if (this.type == "Big") {
        return bigCarProperties = {}; 
   } else {
        return smallCarProperties = {}; 
   }
} 

public send(): void {
  this.save(this.getCarProperties(this.type));
}

public save(car:Car) : void {
 ....
}
```

Comment: What do you think, should it be complicated by OOP?

Comment: So, I suppose that validation will be the same logic like save()

Comment: Validation method can be run before getCarProperties you dont need to go to save if the data are invalid just check before you do anything

Comment: If you share more of your code we can give more solutions

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the pattern of using `if` and `switch` statements to handle differences, you'll end up with lots of conditional statements.

A basic strategy will move those differences into a class, rather than testing properties or types to branch the logic.

```
interface Car {
    save(): void;
}

class SmallCar implements Car {
    protected hasTrolleyHandle: boolean = true;

    save() {
        console.log('Save small car properties.', JSON.stringify(this));
    }
}

class BigCar implements Car {
    protected hasBullBars: boolean = false;

    save() {
        console.log('Save big car properties.', JSON.stringify(this));
    }
}

// Examples
const smallCar = new SmallCar();
smallCar.save();

const bigCar = new BigCar();
bigCar.save();

// More examples
function saveCar(car: Car) {
    car.save();
}

saveCar(smallCar);
saveCar(bigCar);
```

There is a small breach of single responsibility as I don't think a car should save itself - but it isn't worth solving the problem at this scale. When things are bigger, you may benefit from repositories and factories.

You can continue this pattern to have different validation for big and small cars and to handle other differences.

If there is a lot of similarity between big and small cards, you might create a base class, or delegate to a class that can handle the similar stuff.